Loop to find month in a date value in excel
I am creating a macro that takes a date from CSVs and with other info that it contains, it gives me some information.
The thing is, the third party who sends me the CSVs, always send it as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy, and i have to change it manually through power query to have all dates as dd/mm/yyyy.
As I am a bit tired of this step, I thought about make excel find the month space by itself and continue the steps without having to format the date.
Hence, the loop I am looking for, is a IF that goes all over field one and field two (fieldone/fieldtwo/yyyy)  and when it finds that the most repeated number, THAT will be the month, and will assignate the datevalue to 1 (american) or 2 (british) depending on what kind of date it is.
Keep in mind that I already set excel earlier to keep the macro despite having american or british date, american is 1 , and british 2, but i need this because there are some months and number combinations that excel may find it hard to assign, for example 1/8 can be January 8th or August 1st
So far I created in the macro, to find 3 types of dates: 1 - american
2 - British
3 - Analyze and suggest.
The step 3 is the one i am missing and need some advice
Here , I make excel find if date type 1 or 2, now i need excel to read through the fields and find the more repeated value , that will be the month. This will avoid excel confuss 1/8 with 8/1
If fechatxt(0) > 12 Then
    BuscarTipoFecha = 1
    Exit Function
End If
If fechatxt(1) > 12 Then
    BuscarTipoFecha = 2
    Exit Function
End If


How do you open the CSV file? Via File->Open? Via Data->From Text/CSV ? Or do you read the data as plain text in VBA?

always send it as dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy It is risky. eg. 01/05/2024 can be parsed as Jan. 5th or May 1st..

Do they change within a csv or only between csv?

I think you are on the right track, but for the loop, just use the UBound of your array and set the default as being type 2. Your loop will only change it to type 1 if it finds a value > 12.
BuscarTipoFecha = 2
For i = 0 to UBound(fechatxt)
   If fechatxt(i) > 12 Then
      BuscarTipoFecha = 1
      Exit Function
   End If
Next i

